# Error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@aws-sdk". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to retrieve an api key that I stored in AWS, I have installed the package using NPM and initialized the project with npm init, the package.json contains the dependency, and I also check the node modules, how ever when I run my code I get an error stating: Failed to resolve module specifier "@aws-sdk". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I don't know how to fix this issue, Any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

```html
import {
    SecretsManagerClient,
    GetSecretValueCommand,
  } from "@aws-sdk";

const secret_name = "MySecret";

const client = new SecretsManagerClient({
  region: "us-west-1",
});

let response;

try {
  response = await client.send(
    new GetSecretValueCommand({
      SecretId: secret_name,
      VersionStage: "AWSCURRENT", // VersionStage defaults to AWSCURRENT if unspecified
    })
  );
} catch (error) {
  // For a list of exceptions thrown, see
  // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
  throw error;
}

const secret = response.SecretString;

const form = document.querySelector('form');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit-button');
const instructions = document.querySelector('.instructions');

//const apiKey = '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';
const apiKey = secret;
const apiUrl = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/';

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const inputText = input.value.trim();
  console.log(inputText)

  if (inputText !== '') {
    submitButton.disabled = true;
    fetch(apiUrl + 'completions', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        model: 'text-davinci-003',
        prompt: `Generate a title based on: "${inputText}" make sure its SEO optimized and catchy.`,
        max_tokens: 100,
        top_p: 1,
        n: 1,
      }),

    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const title = data.choices[0].text.trim();
        const result = document.createElement('p');
        result.textContent = `Title: ${title}`;
        form.parentNode.insertBefore(result, form.nextSibling);
        if (title !== '') {
          instructions.textContent = '';
        }
        submitButton.disabled = false;
        console.log(data.choices[0].text);

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        submitButton.disabled = false;
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: How, exactly, are you attempting to run your code?

Comment: Are you using Vite as your bundler? I'm having a similar issue

Answer (score -1):

Using relative path, you can try to import the module as below. Modify the `node_modules` path as per your project structure.

```
import { SecretsManagerClient } from "../../node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager/dist-es/SecretsManagerClient.js";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing, i tried it this way aslo, but I still get the same error message

Comment: Can you post your folder structure over here? From which file are you trying to import this? and where is the `node_modules` folder located.

Comment: Probably, you'll have to import like `../../node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager`. I have updated my answer. Can you try that

Comment: No, if a package is installed in the `node_modules` folder, there is no need to use a local import (ie something like `./node_modules/...`)

Comment: The node_modules is located in a folder called WebTest, my index.html, index.js and css are also in the same folder, no other subfolders there just the node modules and the files. I tried to use thje ../../ but then i get an error stating: Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: Yeah, so if you check the @aws/client-secrets-manager folder, there are 3 different folders inside that. There is one more folder called `dist-es`. Try to import file from that folder

Comment: I have updated the answer with new path. Try that

Comment: Where does your certainty come from that the `node_modules` folder is two folders up from that file?

Comment: I don't know. That's just a direction. I have mentioned that. Update the path as per the project structure. The reason I've asked to import like this is because, I don't think this is a react project or this project uses webpack. So normal import doesn't work. That's why we need to provide relative path

Comment: So I tried everithing, I still keep getting the same error message